# Why after inputing the 20th character in this function, the realloc raise an error in c

Tags: c

I will be very grateful if you can tell me why in this c program after inputing the 20th character in `my_input()` function, the `realloc()` raise an error and the program returns this: "Process returned -1073740940 (0xC0000374)". Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUFF_SIZE 20

void my_input(char *s);

void main()
{
    char *text;
    printf("Input text: ");
    my_input(&text);
    printf("%s", &text);
}

void my_input(char *s)
{
    *s = (char*) calloc (BUFF_SIZE, sizeof(char));
    int size = BUFF_SIZE;
    int position = 0;
    char c = getche();
    while (c != 13)
    {
        if (c >= 32 && c <= 126)
        {
            if (position < size - 1)
            {
                s[position] = c;
            }
            else
            {
                char *temp = (char*) calloc (size, sizeof(char));
                strcpy(temp, s);
                size += BUFF_SIZE;
                *s = (char*) realloc (s, size*sizeof(char));
                strcpy(s, temp);
                free(temp);
                s[position] = c;
            }
        }
        else if (c == 8)
        {
            s[position - 1] = '\0';
            position -= 2;
            printf(" %c", 8);
        }
        c = getche();
        position++;
    }
    s[position] = '\0';
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: `void my_input(char **s)` and `printf("%s\n", text);`

Comment: [ALSO: you are leaking memory. And you should avoid the {13,32,128,8,etc} literals]

Comment: temp is unnecessary since realloc preserves data.

Comment: the function `getche()` returns an `int` not a `char`  so (depending on the implement) may be unable to recognize EOF

Comment: there are only two valid signatures for `main()` they are `int main( void )` and `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`  NOtice that they both have a return type of `int`, not `void`

Comment: note that in c, using a bare name of an array degrades to the address of the first byte of the array.  so this statement: `my_input(&text);`  is passing the wrong type of parameter to `my_input()`

Comment: in C, the return type of the memory/heap allocation functions `calloc` `realloc` and `malloc` is `char*` (which can be assigned to any pointer)  Casting the returned type just clutters the code and is often wrong

Comment: several functions in the C library need to be properly prototyped.  Such functions as `free()` `calloc()` `realloc()`. etc need t have the header file `stdlib.h` included

Comment: the string handling functions like `strcpy()` need to be properly prototyped.  Usually be including the header file `string.h`

Comment: when compiling always enable the warnings so the compiler can tell you about the above problems